# Opencart Upgrade from 2.3.0.2 to 3.0.2.0

Tags: opencart2.3, opencart-3

I've just upgraded from 2.3.0.2 to 3.0.2.0

upgradation is successful but it's saying:

[image]

I've found one solution, to goto Extensions > Extensions, select Themes from drop-down. Edit the store and check if the status is enabled and the relevant theme is selected and save.
but, I've no Extension menu in navigation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to system>user_groups>edit user with which you are logged in >check access permission/modify permission for all. You will be able to see Extension.